# How can I get particles to emit with a rotation based off of the rotation of the face it was emitted from

Tags: modeling, particles

I'm relatively new to blender and I would like to get this hexagon model to emit rotated toward the face it was emitted from. Here's what I have, [image: The problem]

If you are confused about something I said, I can clarify some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ParticleSettings for the emitter, turn on Rotation and set Initial Rotation to Normal. In my example I also set gravity to 0, as shown, as it seems you did also.

Orient your particle object in edit mode in a way that its local y-axis points to the forward direction you like it to have. You can see its local axis by turning on Axis in Display tab of the object properties for the particle object.

[image]

[image]

You might also want to have a look over the [manual section on particle rotation](http://www.blender.org/manual/physics/particles/physics/introduction.html#rotation).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me, I must be making a stupid mistake somewhere, here's a [picture](http://puu.sh/j8Lgf/c8721011b4.png/) of my blender following what you did, and thanks a lot for putting up with me and my lack of knowledge of blender!

Comment: Sorry it didn't work for you, I hope I didn't miss anything. I can't see anything wrong in your image. I edited my answer and added my blend file so you can download it and have a look.

Comment: Ah, my problem seems to be that I had grid selected, and it doesn't work the same way with rotation. Thanks for providing the .blend file for me to look at!